# Laravel group by multiple level

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

How to `GROUP BY` multiple levels in Laravel. I've tried this code.

I've also used `toArray()` then `array_values()`, but same result as using `values()`

**EDIT: Sorry, I wrote value() instead of values()**

When using values(), `product_name` not showing.

```
// Controller
$products = DB::table('product_registrations')
    // ->select(['product_name', 'color'])
       ->join('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'product_registrations.color_id')
       ->join('sizes', 'sizes.id', '=', 'product_registrations.size_id')
       ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_registrations.product_id')
       ->get()
       ->groupBy(['product_name', 'color']);
       // ->values(); // I've used values(), it worked but first level groupBy name missing

return response()->json(['products' => $products]);

---

I want something like: 

products: [
    product1: [
        color1: {},
        color2: {}
    ]
]
```

**Without values()**

```
{
    "products": {
        "light blue dress": {
            "Ягаан": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "color_id": 1,
                    "size_id": 6,
                    "color": "Ягаан",
                    "product_name": "light blue dress",
                }
            ],
        },
    }
}
```

**With values()**

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "Ягаан": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "color_id": 1,
                    "size_id": 6,
                    "color": "Ягаан",
                    "product_name": "light blue dress",
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Ягаан" means pink color in Mongolia xD

Comment: please don't use screenshots for this - copy-paste the code in the question. As well I don't understand what is wrong with your solution without `value()`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert, ok, I've just updated the post. I've read your blog post about this, but It just returns an object instead of an array.

Comment: Sorry, also could you please explain why the deepest level is an array while others not

Comment: Thanks for updating - can you please share the code that you are expecting using the same details? I'm actually still confused on what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the code that I'm expecting, what do you mean by that? I've put a code snippet of my `index` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I also have problem on this last week but I manage to get through.

```
$products::latest()->get();

$products = products->groupBy(function($product) {
  return $product->name;
});

$products = products->map(function($product) {
  return $product->groupBy(function($prod) {
    return $prod->color;
  });
});

return $products;
```

You can also optimize this method by using `array_only` this method is only for laravel

Comment: Sorry, It still gives me the same result - it returns object not array

Comment: the thing I made is to make the object to array in my javascript because I cant map directly in it

Comment: Yep, me too xD, I've decided to make some grouping in JS